# Is the group of upper triangular matrices isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let 
$$
G = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & y \\ 0 & 1 & z \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} : x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

I have shown that the set $G$ with the operation of matrix multiplication is a non-abelian subgroup of $SL(3, \mathbb R)$.

**Now, is $G$ isomorphic to the group comprising $\mathbb R^3=\{(x,y,z):x,y,z$ are in $\mathbb R\}$ with the operation of vector addition**.

I know I have to show the map is a homomorphism and that it is bijective. I have done the process successfully with simpler groups but don't know what to do for a matrix and vector.

Comment: You already shown that it is not abelian, so clearly it cannot be isomorphic to the given group.

Comment: See the extensive article on the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group).

Comment: I changed your title.  Isomorphism is a relation *between* groups.  You can't "show a group is isomorphic" any more than you can "show five is less than."

Answer (score 1):

Tobias has nailed it.  It's important to understand what isomorphism between groups means.

Yes, two groups are isomorphic if there is a bijective homomorphism between them.  But more importantly, it means they are *indistinguishable* as far as groups go.  Poincaré said that mathematics is the art of calling different things by the same name.  Isomorphic groups get the same “name” in algebra.

If $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic, any group-theoretic property of $G$ must also hold in $G'$.  By “group-theoretic property” I mean any property of the group which depend only on group axioms.  Abelianness is such a property.  Thus, if $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic, they are either both abelian or both nonabelian.

One way to show that two groups are not isomorphic is to find a group-theoretic property that one holds and the other does not.  It's easier and cleaner than assuming there is an isomorphism and trying to derive a contradiction.

Let $G'$ be the group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under addition.  Your parametrization of $G$ shows that there are plenty of bijections between them.  But you've also shown that $G$ is nonabelian, while $G'$ is clearly abelian.  So the groups cannot be isomorphic.